# NxWheelShape Tilt with Vision(Havok) Engine and PhysX 2.8.x

Tags: c++, physics, physx

A vehicle I am working on has front wheels that can tilt(lean) left and right as well as turn left and right. The turning was pretty easy, but there seems to be nothing on how to set a WheelShapes tilt and I'm wondering if anyone here has experience with this and can point me in the right direction?

I see there is a SetRotationMatrix() but it also says that it bypasses physics module and will lead to unpredictable results so I was looking into a Vision Engine function that allows me to set a Rotation Delta by passing in a yaw, pitch and roll but that doesn't affect the WheelShape itself, only the 3D Wheel Model and I don't think thats what i want anyway.

I only mention the Vision Engine in case anyone is familiar with both but the PhysX stuff is mostly untouched by the engine. Any suggestions?

Comment: I'm curious why you're using PhysX in an engine that employs Havok?

Comment: Mainly because we have been using Vision for a couple years now and I guess PhysX was the option then. Our current schedule doesn't allow us much time to work on switching over and training, but we want to.

Answer (score 1):

So I got it figured out. Turns out that some of the other coders had to multiply a couple matrices to get the wheels to stand up in the first place so the work I was doing was working, just resetting the wheels back to flat and then tilting. I just multiplied my new matrix with the original and voila =-)